# Implement PATCH operation with Play forms

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi there I am getting some troubles implementing patch operation using Play framework and forms (according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902). The idea is to then pattern match on the patch operation to decide what is the action to take. So far what I achieved to do :

```
 val myForm = Form(
      tuple(
        "op" -> text.verifying(List("replace", "add").contains(_)),
        "path" -> text.verifying(List("/X", "/Y").contains(_)),
        "value" -> of[AnyRef] //does not compile :'(
      )
    )
```

Resulting the following error : "Cannot find Formatter type class for AnyRef."

How can I workaround this, knowing that my value field can be of a different type depending on the targeted subresource ?

Comment: may be `value` verify as "non empty string" and after you can parse to necessary type?

Comment: I was planning to do pattern matching on my AnyRef object so it's flexible and nice looking. But that would be a way to do it as well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the Play Forms but instead basic readers, doing something like :

```
 case class PatchOperation(operation: String, path: String, value: JsValue)

  implicit val patchOperationReads: Reads[PatchOperation] = (
    (JsPath \ "op").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "path").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "value").read[JsValue]
    ) (PatchOperation.apply _)
```

and in my controller

```
request.body.asJson.map(js => js.validate[PatchOperation] match {
        case JsSuccess(patch, path) => {
          patch match {
            case PatchOperation("replace", "/subresource1", value) =>
              //here do something and parse the value
            case PatchOperation("add", "/subresource1", value) =>
              //here do something and parse the value
            case _ => BadRequest
          }
        }
        case JsError(patchOperation) => BadRequest
      }) getOrElse BadRequest
```